# I want to animate a word being written on a website, i have png files, how can i realise that

Tags: javascript, css, animation, fonts

Hey stackoverflow community !

I have question about a client project of mine. My clients wants his logo (which is a handwritten word) to be animated on their website. How can i realise this using css/js ? The client sent me a series of png images (over 100 in total), which 'animate' the hand writing, but i think this might be overkill considering file sizes and load on the client site when entering the website. And besides that, i dont really know how i can implement that.

In a personal project I played around with SVG animation of single letters with stroke and stroke dasharray offset parameters via css. But somehow for that project it doesnt really work because the font is literally custom in the sense that its hand written by the client.

I am thankful for any tips on how i can realize this with a png/svg image of the handwritten logo as base. Because I am stuck with this and dont really know how to realize this.

thanks, eS

I tried to convert the pngs in a gif, which works but ruins the quality and resolution of the writing, but i only tried a gif-creator i found on the internet, maybe someone has a tip on how to keep the resolution high?

Comment: I would have suggested a gif too but if that isn’t suitable how about making your own mp4. That way you will be loading the images using HTML/JS just the once and from there on will have only the one file to load. I’ve done this using the simple inbuilt recording on an iPad and quality is fine, good enough for a signature assuming the originals are high enough quality.

Comment: thanks alot for your suggestion i will give it a try as an mp4. 
I was just looking for another way to potentially make it animatable via css or js so i can use things like a scroll trigger etc :)

Answer (score 0):

I think is the same technique of mask animation

maybe this can help you
https://youtu.be/dldpud1PuL8